# Como saber se alguém está usando um proxy para acessar meu website

Tags: php, proxy

Com a linguagem PHP tem como eu saber se o usuário está usando um proxy para camuflar seu IP real?
Estou falando dessas proxys aqui -> http://www.freeproxylists.net/

Comment: Se você tiver sorte verifique se existe o `X-Forwarded-For` e o `X-Client-IP`, se houver ele está usando proxy. Se não você tem algumas técnicas, uma dela é saber se o IP é de um proxy, como você mesmo mencionou. Se alguém se conectar com um dos IPs dessa lista ele está usando proxy, logo use o `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, normalmente e compare com a lista de proxies.

Comment: Acabei de verificar aqui, estou usando proxy e nada apontou, afs q mentira. Será que em outra linguagem isso é mais é eficaz?